# Best practice in writing queries in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to know whats the best practice in writing a database (mysql) query in codeigniter. i have seen many different ways but was confused what would be the best practice.

Following are few methods i have gone through

Method 1

```
$this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
$this -> db -> from('users');
$this -> db -> where('username = ' . "'" . $username . "'");
$this -> db -> where('password = ' . "'" . MD5($password) . "'");
$this -> db -> limit(1);
```

Method 2

```
$query = $this->db->query("select * from user where username = '$uname' and password = '$pass'");
```

Method 3 (writing a stored procedure)

```
$query = "call authenticateuser(" . $this->db->escape($parameters['username']) . ", '" . sha1($parameters['password']) . "')";
```

There might may be many other ways, but would like to know what the best way in writing a query, therefore if anyone could advise, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Active records is the best practice.

Comment: The problem with all the above methods are that they are open to SQL injection. You should really make use of the available parameters and write your WHERE functions like this `$this -> db -> where('username',$username);` . Which will automatically escape the strings for you.

Comment: Note: be careful. Codeigniter uses old `mysql_*` functions for escaping which is in the process of deprecation. Even if you are using codeigniter, please change the default driver to pdo.

Comment: Apparently, you could just switch the database config to use the mysqli_*() driver instead of the mysql_*() one, which should solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Active records` so best is method1 with little refactoring:

```
$this->db->select('id, username, password');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
$this->db->limit(1);
```

check your `where()` and mine `where()` :)

Active record query building is more comfortable, and readable when building queries, expecially if you need many filters `where,like,order_by,join,limit` writing down by hands the queries should be probably little faster, but i encourage you to use active record building.

Comment: 1st of all, it is NOT active record. Codeigniter developers are butchering the whole terms. This is just query builder and nothing else. 2nd, saw queries are always faster than active record/query builder. Third, for complicated queries, active record fails to perform because that is not what it is for.

Comment: so they should change their doc, i just report what is inside http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html and it is called **Active Record**

Comment: @Ispuk, you should probably mention why your method is better.

Comment: Note, method 2 could also be acceptable if rewritten in the format: `$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?', array($username));`.

Comment: he should ask better which is the best practice for a specific query he gives, anyway when possible active records always is my choice, don't know if you agree

Comment: That is not the point. For marketing, codeigniter can use any misleading product information. It is our duty to notify new users that, its not what it promises.

Comment: erm i don't see what not to agree there. A product is giving false ads. A person came to you asking for a review. If you know something was wrong, you'l prefer to hide it and recomment it to him?

Comment: i not agree with the fact that it's up to users to correct owner project mistakes, if i'm newbie and i first time come on user guide, i read Active records and that is how i will call them quite forever :D

Comment: but if you are using it, you will be the victim, not the owner. The owner won't take any responsibility for your damage.

Comment: sure, what i mean is THEY not me has to correct that on user guide :

Answer (score 0):

i usually this to get data from database, it very easy and quick;

My model:

```
public function getdata($select,$table,$where,$limit,$offset,$order){

        if(isset($select) && !empty($select)){
            $this->db->select("$select");
        }
        if(isset($limit) && !empty($limit)){
            if(isset($offset) && !empty($offset)){
                $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
            }
            else{
                $this->db->limit($limit);
            }
        }
        if(isset($where) && !empty($where)){
            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->where($key,$value);
            }
        }
        if(isset($order) && !empty($order)){
            foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->order_by($key,$value);
            }
        }

        $query = $this->db->get("$table");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

My Controller:

```
$this->my_model->getdata('','user',array('userid' =>  1,'username' => 'my_username'),'','','');
```

this means:

```
select * from user where userid = 1 and username = 'my_username';
```

other example:

```
$this->my_model->getdata('username','user','',10,'','','');
```

means:

```
select username from user limit 10;

//my_model is model class name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I'm using Stored Procedure although it is tedious in coding but the advantage are easy in maintenance, security and speed.
Here is my example:

```
   function user_list($str_where, $str_order, $str_limit){

     $str_where  = $this->db->call_function('real_escape_string', $this->db->conn_id, $str_where);
    $str_order  = $this->db->call_function('real_escape_string', $this->db->conn_id, $str_order);
    $str_limit  = $this->db->call_function('real_escape_string', $this->db->conn_id, $str_limit);

$qry_res    = $this->db->query("CALL rt_sample_list('{$str_where}', '{$str_order}', '{$str_limit}');");
    $res        = $qry_res->result();

    $qry_res->next_result(); // Dump the extra resultset.
    $qry_res->free_result(); // Does what it says.

    return $res;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I use my own crud_model which is based upon CI's Active record in actual. It's better to pass `$params` array rather flooding functions with parameters.

**In my Model:**

```
//for JOINS etc stuff

public function get_joined_data($params){

    if (!empty($params['select'])) {
        $this->db->select($params['select']);
    }
    $this->db->from($params['from']);

    if (is_array($params['join']) || count($params['join']) > 1) {
        foreach ($params['join'] as $key => $value) {
            $join_values = explode(',', $value);
            $this->db->join($join_values[0], $join_values[1], $join_values[2]);
        }
    } else{
        $join_values = explode(',', $params['join'][0]);
        $this->db->join($join_values[0], $join_values[1], $join_values[2]);
    }

    if (!empty($params['key']) && !empty($params['where'])) {
        $this->db->where($params['key'], $params['where']);
    } else if (is_array($params['where'])) {

        $this->db->where($params['where']);
    }
    if (isset($params['like']) && is_array($params['like'])) {
        $this->db->like($params['like']);
    }
    if (isset($params['orderby']) && is_array($params['orderby'])) {
        foreach ($params['orderby'] as $name => $order) {
            $this->db->order_by($name, $order);
        }
    }
    if (isset($params['limit'])) {
        $this->db->limit($params['limit']['count'], $params['limit']['start']);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**And in Controller:**

```
//joins()

$params = array(
    'from' => '$from',
    'join' => $join_arr,  
    'where' => $where_arr, 
    'orderby' => $orderby_arr 
    );`enter code here`
$donors_data = $this->crud_model->get_joined_data($params);
```